# Conditionally render border colour React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to conditionally change my border color based on whether the textInput is under focus or not.

```
<View
style={focus? { ...styles.inputRow, ...bgColorOnFocus }: { ...styles.inputRow, ...bgColorOnBlur }}>
```

This works as expected, but I'm having to repeat inputRow styles twice. I've been trying to improve the code with the following code where I add the object based on whether it's on focus or not and it's throwing an error.

```
<View style ={
{...styles.inputRow, focus? ...bgColorOnFocus: ...bgColorOnBlur}}
>
```

I'm not sure if I'm being silly, or if there's something missing that I'm not familiar with? Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a `style` prop accept an array as a value:

```
<View style={[styles.inputRow, isFocus ? bgColorOnFocus : bgColorOnBlur]}>
```

is a valid way to conditionally render some style.